# What does the GRANT MONITOR ON SCHEMA allow in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The [Access Control Privileges documentation in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html) only says :

> Grants ability to see details within an object (e.g. queries and usage
> within a warehouse).

So what details specifically (regarding schemas) is referrering to?

Is it just the ability of performing `DESCRIBE SCHEMA  xxx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's exactly the ability to perform DESCRIBE SCHEMA command.

So to be able to use this ability, you also need to have usage rights on the target database and the schema.